How do I redirect the output of mongorestore to a log file?
Here is the command I'm trying to redirect the output of:
$ docker exec -it container sh -c 'mongorestore --archive' < ~/db.dump

I attempted to just do:
$ docker exec -it container sh -c 'mongorestore --archive' < ~/db.dump > restore.log

I'm sure there are forums showing how to do this, but I wasn't even sure how to google how to do what I want to do. Any help would be appreciated.

You need to do the redirection within the sh -c command.
docker exec -it container sh -c 'mongorestore --archive < /db.dump > /restore.log 2>&1'

Using 2>&1 redirects standard error to standard output, so both are captured in the log file.

Drop the -t. It tells Docker to open a virtual terminal and connect that to the executed process's input and output, which messes with redirection. You'll only need that when you want to interact with the process using terminal features.
This should work:
docker exec -i container sh -c 'mongorestore --archive' < ~/db.dump > restore.log

The -i is still needed as you need the input of the executed process to be connected the redirected input of the docker command.
